# Find out which database entry has changed

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, typo3

I have a field in my typo3 backend. If i add something to the field and click "save" then an entry in the database is created.

What i try is to find out which table is modified in my database, after i add a new item to the field and click save.

I found out that there is a tracking option in phpmyadmin, but im not sure if this function is what i am searching for.

[image]

My ui is in german, "Nachverfolgung" means "tracking".

How can i find this out?

Comment: It's unclear what the question is here. Do you need to figure out what tables will be edited by added a record in the backend or do you need to track changes after they have been made?

Comment: I need to figure out what records/tables etc. will be changed/added in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open one of the records containing the field in question in the TYPO3 backend, and inspect the field using the developer tools of your browser.

In TYPO3 7.6 and upwards check the attribute `data-formengine-input-name` of the input field, in TYPO3 6.2 and downwards check the `name` attribute of the input field (or sometimes a hidden field besides it). Its value will look somehow like this:

```
data[tx_news_domain_model_news][6][author_email]
```

The value in the first pair of brackets is the table name, the value in the second pair is the records `uid`, and the value between the last pair is the field name. So in the example, the table name would be `tx_news_domain_model_news` and the field name is `author_email`.